# Getting InvalidArgumentError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open while working with tf.data on the custom image dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(_parseJpeg, num_parallel_calls = nthread)

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)     
dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
images, labels = iterator.get_next()

 with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([images, labels])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Python\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)
>     File "D:\Python\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
>     File "D:\Python\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string) : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   ; Unknown error
>            [[Node: ReadFile = ReadFile]]
>            [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,224,224,3], [?,1000]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>            [[Node: IteratorGetNext/_1 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_37_IteratorGetNext", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "vgg16_train_batch_processing.py", line 231, in 
>       sess.run(optimizer)
>     File "D:\Python\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 877, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "D:\Python\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1100, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
>     File "D:\Python\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)
>     File "D:\Python\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string) : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   ; Unknown error
>            [[Node: ReadFile = ReadFile]]
>            [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,224,224,3], [?,1000]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>            [[Node: IteratorGetNext/_1 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_37_IteratorGetNext", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, fixed the problem myself.

It was in the parser function for dataset map.

Instead of `tf.read_file(filename)`, I put `tf.read_file(str(filename))` by mistake,
which was causing the error because `filename` here is a tensor.